# What is the Behavior of a Dynamic Attribute in a Static (Extension) Class in C# (MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, static

I am new to developing in .NET and C#, but have been a long-time developer, working with C, C++, Java, PHP, etc.

I have an MVC3 extension class for my data models that refers to the database.  It is set as "private static" in the class, but I think that it is not keeping up with database changes.  In other words, when I change data in the controllers, those changes aren't "noticed" in the db because it is static. Currently, I am creating and disposing of the variable for each use, to compensate.

My questions are:

1. Am I correct that a static db variable could behave that way?
2. Is it necessary to dispose of the dynamic variable in the static class, or will garbage collection still take care of it automatically?

Here is a relevant snippet of the class:

```
namespace PBA.Models {
    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using PBA.Models;
    using PBA.Controllers;

    public static class Extensions {
        private static PbaDbEntities db = null;

        public static PbaDbEntities GetDb() {
            // TODO: find out about static memory/disposal, etc.
            //
            if (db != null) {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            db = new PbaDbEntities();
            return db;
        }

        public static string GetCheckpointState(this Activity activity, long memberProjectId) {
            GetDb();  // TODO: Do I need to do this each time, or will a one-time setting work?

            string state = CheckpointController.CHECKPOINT_STATUS_NOT_STARTED;
            try {
                var sub = db.ActivitySubmissions.
                    Where(s => s.activityId == activity.activityId).
                    Where(s => s.memberProjectId == memberProjectId).
                    OrderByDescending(s => s.submitted).
                    First();
                if (sub != null) {
                    state = sub.checkpointStatusId;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
// omitted for brevity
                }
                return state;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't swallow all exceptions.

Comment: You're using neither `dynamic` nor attributes.

Comment: I think you really don't understand what `static` means. You should read up about that. Also, in C# non-static members are called instance members, not “dynamic”.

Comment: As I indicated in the text, this is a snippet to demonstrate the question.  Your comment doesn't address the questions I raised.  The terminology I am using is from programming in general, not from C#.  The term "dynamic" is used generally for heap allocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will fail horribly in production.
DataContexts are not thread-safe; you *must not* share a context between requests.

Never put mutable objects in static fields in multi-threaded applications.

Comment: Why would I call SaveChanges(), when I am doing only selects here?

Comment: You're right; I misunderstood the problem.  However, your code is still wrong; you should just use a local variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it will fail horribly?  It is not clear to me how the code is sharing a context if it is getting a new context each time an operation is performed.

Comment: What if two requests call `GetCheckpointState()` simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring exceptions that way is a terrible idea, if you don't want to handle exceptions just don't try/catch, or catch & rethrow.  Think about it like this, after you've buried the exception, your program is in an invalid state, b/c something you have no control over error'd out.  Now, b/c you've buried the exception, your program can continue to operate but it's in a bad state.

If your code makes it to production, 3.5 yrs from now some jr. programmer is going to get involved in some middle of the night firestorm because all of a sudden the website is broken, even though it used to work.  It will be completely impossible to track down where the exception is happening so, this poor guy is going to spend 48 straight hours adding logging code all over the place to track down the problem.  He will find that some DBA somewhere decided to rename the column MemberProjectId to MemberProjectIdentifier, which caused your linq to blow up.

Think of the children, handle exceptions, don't bury them.

btw - yes, i have been that guy that has to figure out these types of mistakes.

Comment: oh man, have you ever seen production code in the enterprise?

Comment: You obviously didn't read the other comments, or my initial description of the code as a "snippet" of relevant portions.  (I have been a developer for 25+ years, producing apps that are used around the world for critical systems.)

Comment: yep, but having a static datacontext should blow up QA as soon it's deployed

Comment: if you are handling the exception good!  if not, you should.  the other problems still stand though.  basically you are using static improperly (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx).  also, no reason to be combative here, you are new to c#, you aren't using it properly, take a deep breath and try and learn something from folks that know what they are talking about.  creating a new context each time the method is called is no good. Try passing the context in to the method.  you should strive for 1 db context per request.

Comment: I've added an example of having a dbcontext per request

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to read about mvc3 and entity framework before writing coding and asking in here for help on something that's coded full of bad practices.

Answering your questions:

1- no

2- makes no sense as the answer to 1

Do it right, here are some useful documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg416514(v=vs.98).aspx

*EDIT: Adding some explicit fix*

You could access your dbcontext from an static class, something like this:

```
var context = DbProvider.CurrentDb;
```

The idea is to access your db from here always: from your extension methods and from your controller actions.

Then, the implementation of the DbProvider.CurrentDb will be something like this:

```
public static classDbProvider {

    public static void Initialize(){
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.BeginRequest += CreateDb;
        HttpConetxt.Current.ApplicationInstance.EndRequest += DisposeDb;
    }

    private static void CreateDb(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        HttpContext.Items.Add("CurrentDb", new PbaDbEntities(););
    }

    private static void DisposeDb(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Current.Dispose();
        HttpContext.Items.Remove("CurrentDb");
    }

    public static PbaDbEntities CurrentDb{
        get {
            return (PbaDbEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it will create a new Db per each request and it will be available ONLY in that request. In that way, your db will be disposed at the end of each request. This pattern is called Open-Session-in-View.

Finally, you need to initialize the `DbProvider` calling the method 
`Initialize()` in your Global.asax file, in the event Application_start.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is an example. For instance, it's too coupled to the web environment and it won't work with unit tests. But it gives you the idea of how to manage it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any idea of the context here-- if db is simply a connection-like object or not, but it appears you are throwing away and recreating whatever it is unnecessarily.

Best to create a property (for whatever your doing) so to be consistent.

```
private static Thing _thing;
private static Thing thing{
  get{
    if(_thing==null){
      _thing=new Thing();
    }
    return _thing;
  }
}
```